# list directory and file of a path and insert into database and create a tree from it C#

Tags: c#, sql, file, tree, directory

i want to create list down all the directories and files in the given path and insert into database using that i want to create a tree structure in ext.net. i will create the tree structure in ext.net but i am unable to create a proper tree structure to insert in the database. will attach my code here. take a look.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string Path;
    DataTable dtTree = new DataTable();
    int NodeID = 1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dtTree.Columns.Add("NodeID", typeof(int));
        dtTree.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dtTree.Columns.Add("IsDirectory", typeof(bool));
        dtTree.Columns.Add("ParentID", typeof(int));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Path = textBox1.Text;
        CreateTree(Path,0);
    }

    public void CreateTree(string path, int ParentNode)
    {

        foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
            DataRow dr = dtTree.NewRow();
            dr["NodeID"] = NodeID;
            dr["Name"] = dirinfo.Name;
            dr["IsDirectory"] = true;
            dr["ParentID"] = ParentNode;

            dtTree.Rows.Add(dr);
            ParentNode = NodeID;
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
            {
                FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(file);
                DataRow dr1 = dtTree.NewRow();
                dr1["ParentID"] = NodeID;
                dr1["NodeID"] = ++NodeID;
                dr1["IsDirectory"] = false;
                dr1["Name"] = fileinfo.Name;

                dtTree.Rows.Add(dr1);
            }
            NodeID++;
            CreateTree(dir, ParentNode);
            //NodeID++;
            ParentNode++;
        }
    }



}
```

}

the datatable represents the table in the same structure as the table in the database. the nodeid is the node of the file or folder and the parent id suggets the parent nodeid of the file or folder.Please help me out with the logic.the root node is 0

Comment: The code posted looks like it is work correctly and can easily be stored into a database.  What type of database are you using.  You should be able to just enumerate through the rows of the datatable and store one row at a time into the database.

Comment: i don't have issue with inserting in the database i have issue in creating the parent child relationship in the datatable i have created this logic but still there are some errors. the datatable formed shows wrong relationship

Comment: Just looks like you are incrementing the NodeID and ParentID incorrectly.

Comment: can you please help me with it

Comment: @jdweng plese help me with it

Comment: i figured it myself thanks